# emit event with arguments from child to parent with ember 3.6

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like emit one event from child to parent but with some argument.

**Child component javascript**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  actions: {
    favoriteWasClicked() {
      const organization = this.get('organization');
      // organization.id value equal to 'facebook' here in my app
      // we're gonna send its id to parent component "orgs" like an argument of clicked method
      this.clicked(organization);
    }
  }
});
```

**Parent component .hbs template**

```
{{child-component
  clicked=(action "favoriteClicked" value="organization.id")
}}
```

**Parent component javascript controller file**

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    favoriteClicked(orgId) {
      console.log(orgId);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm getting **undefined** in **console.log(orgId);** Why? What am i missing

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to change `organization.id` to just `id`. What I mean is; you need to do the following:

```
{{child-component
  clicked=(action "favoriteClicked" value="id")
}}
```

You send the event from the child component with an organization; which simply contains an `id`; but not `organization.id`; so it must be just `id` for the `value` property in the `action` passing within parent's template.

I prepared an [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/147db2db37fa5fc8fe5496de49e9c514?openFiles=components.parent-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.child-component.hbs) for you to illustrate the solution I proposed in action. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it possible add severals arguments? i'm trying something like `clicked=(action "favoriteClicked" value="id, favorites")` but `id` is avoided... Thank you again!

Comment: @ntj34 AFAIK you can only specify just one property name as the `value` property of the `action`. I checked the official guide and it seems like what I know.

Comment: Thank you again :)